# Evaluate $\iint_{R} \sqrt{|(y-x^2)|}dxdy $ where R = [-1,1;0,2]

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

I have taken $ \int_{0}^2\int_{-1}^{1} f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{-1}^{1}{\int_{0}^2 f(x,y)dy}dx$. Since f(x,y) is continuous. Integrating wrt y, I got $I = {2/3}\int_{-1}^{1} {|2-x^2|}^{3/2}dx$.
How to solve this integral? Any substitution tips

Comment: You could use trig substitution $x =\sqrt{2} \sin{u}$

Comment: Thank you @Triatticus. Can you tell me whether my approach is correct?

Comment: Well the evaluation of the limits in y is not correct you should have more than one term as a result